# MySQL foreign constraint delete on boolean change

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl, cascade

I was thinking about implementing a user registration system. Where will be *'users'* and *'user_activation'* tables.

if my tables looked like this: *table -> fields*:

```
users -> id,username,activated(boolean), etc.

user_activation -> users_id (foreign key constraint obviously),token, etc.
```

Now, I can cascade delete the token data from *'user_activation'* if a user is deleted from *'users'* table.

I was wondering how would I achieve the same when the *'activated'* boolean value in *'users'* table would be set to *'true'*?

(once a user is activated , the token would be useless, so it should be deleted once user is activated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this with a foreign key, but you could use a trigger:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER user_activation_tr
BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.activated THEN
        DELETE FROM user_activation WHERE users_id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END;//

delimiter ;
```